# How can I remove objects from ActionController::Parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

I am trying to remove an element from my ActionController::Parameters object, but it doesn't work as I was expecting.  My `report_params` object is as follows,

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"51956915", "author_id"=>"1", "workout_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"player_id"=>"14155", "date"=>"2017-10-09", "report_id"=>"51956915"} permitted: true> permitted: true>
```

I want to execute the following to remove `workout_attributes` from the object.

```
report_params.extract!(:workout_attributes)
```

And this returns the information below, but it still exists when I rerun `report_params`

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"player_id"=>"14155", "date"=>"2017-10-09", "report_id"=>"51956915"} permitted: true>
```

When I rerun `report_params` in console...

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"51956915", "author_id"=>"1", "workout_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"player_id"=>"14155", "date"=>"2017-10-09", "report_id"=>"51956915"} permitted: true> permitted: true>
```

**Update**
Here's the report_params method from the controller:

```
def report_params
  params.require(:report).permit(:id, :author_id, 
        workout_attributes: [:player_id, :report_id, :date]
        )
end
```

So am I not allowed to edit the `report_params` object and i need to make a copy of it and then pass that copy to my update function in the action?  Or is there something here I'm not doing correctly? Thanks!

**Update with a "Working" Solution**

I've found if I do the following, essentially making a copy of the params and then editing and passing on - it works.  But this seems like ugly code if it can be done with the actual original params object.

```
  modified_report_params = report_params
  modified_report_params.extract!(:workout_attributes)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      if @report.update(modified_report_params)
      # ...
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permitting params creates a new object:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(a: 1, b: 2)
params.object_id
#=> 70277626506220
params.permit(:a, :b).object_id #new object created
#=> 70277626332020
```

As you can see, each time, when you call `report_params` you create a new object from `params`. To fix your issue, you can mutate `params` itself:

```
params.extract!(:workout_attributes)
```

Or, by using memoization:

```
def report_params
  @report_params ||= params
    .require(:report)
    .permit(:id, :author_id, workout_attributes: [:player_id, :report_id, :date])
end
report_params.extract!(:workout_attributes)
#=><ActionController::Parameters {"player_id"=>"14155", "date"=>"2017-10-09", "report_id"=>"51956915"} permitted: true>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
params.except(:password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Hash#except`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) instead of `#extract!`.

> #### except(*keys)
>
> Returns a hash that includes everything except given keys.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    if @report.update(report_params.except(:workout_attributes))
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from HashWithIndifferentAccess in Rails 5. But this class has its own method `except`, true.